# AttributeError: 'HashingTF' object has no attribute '_java_obj'

Tags: pyspark

when I use the pyspark.ml.Pipline to create pipline, it occurs the following problem:
  File "/opt/module/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/Pipeline.py", line 18, in 
    hashingTF = HashingTF(ipnutCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(),outputCol="features")
  File "/opt/module/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/**init**.py", line 110
, in wrapper
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ipnutCol'
Exception ignored in: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/module/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 4
0, in **del**
AttributeError: 'HashingTF' object has no attribute '_java_obj'

I guess the API have changed, but I am not certain.

```
#　构建一个机器学习流水线
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, Tokenizer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
# 创建一个SparkSession对象
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("WorldCount").getOrCreate()

# 1. prepare training documents from a list of (id, text, label) tuples
training = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 'a b c d e spark', 1.0),
    (1, 'b d', 0.0),
    (2, 'spark f g h', 1.0),
    (3, 'hadoop mapreduce', 0.0)
],['id','text','label'])
# 2. 定义pipline 中各个流水线阶段PipelineStage.
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text", outputCol="words")
hashingTF = HashingTF(ipnutCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(),outputCol="features")
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.001)

# 3. 按照具体的处理逻辑有序地组织PipelineStages,并创建一个Pipeline.
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer,hashingTF,lr])

# 4. 训练模型
model = pipeline.fit(training)

# 5. 构建测试数据
test = spark.createDataFrame([
    (4, 'spark i j k'),
    (5, 'i m n'),
    (6, 'spark hadoop spark'),
    (7, 'apache hadoop')
],['id', 'text'])

# 6. 调用之前训练好的PipelineModel的transform()方法，
# 让测试数据按照顺序通过拟合的流水线，生成预测结果
prediction = model.transform(test)
selected = prediction.select('id','text','probability','prediction')
for row in selected.collect():
    rid, text, prob, prediction = row
    print('({},{}) -> prob = {}, prediction={}'.format(rid, text, str(prob),prediction))
```

(4, spark i j k) --> prob=[0.155543713844,0.844456286156], prediction=1.000000 (5, l m n) --> prob=[0.830707735211,0.169292264789], prediction=0.000000 (6, spark hadoop spark) --> prob=[0.0696218406195,0.93037815938], prediction=1.000000 (7, apache hadoop) --> prob=[0.981518350351,0.018481649649], prediction=0.000000

Answer (score 0):

Your spelling of `input` is wrong here (`ipnutCol`):

```
TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ipnutCol'
```